# Why ansible not including handler?

Tags: ansible

I am writing a role where I am including handler. This is the structure I have :

```
role-->
   |____>handlers---> main.yml
   |____>tasks------> main.yml
              ------> controller.yml
```

Here is the code:
handlers/main.yml

```
---
- name: Restart Jenkins
  service: name=jenkins state=restarted
```

inside controller.yml I am using it like:

```
  notify: restart Jenkins
```

But when I run the role it gives me this error:

```
ERROR! The requested handler 'restart Jenkins' was not found in any of the known handlers
```

Ansible version I have is ansible 2.1.1.0

Comment: mind the case! `restart`/`Restart`

Comment: no that din't work

Answer (score 4):

This is simply a case of improper capitalization. You have `notify: restart Jenkins` when it should be `notify: Restart Jenkins`

Comment: I changed it to ---
- name: restart jenkins
  service: name=jenkins state=restarted           notify: restart jenkins still it is failing

Comment: could you update your question with the exact syntax of the updated code and the new error?